# Want to scrape each category's URL and loop through it until found the product URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping https://www.americanflags.com/flags.html and want to extract OTHERS FLAGS URLs.

I have scraped categories' URLs and stored them in list.

```
listofurls = ['https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/pow-mia-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/police-fire-thin-line-ems.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/911-honor-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/government-specified-flags-accessories.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/gift-certificates.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/novelty-celebration-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/holiday-seasonal-flags-banners.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/nautical-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/city-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/political-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/iso-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/desk-stick-flag-sets.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/us-state-territory-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/world-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/historic-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/sports-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/religious-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/advertising-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/custom-flags-banners.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/political-flags/protest-flags.html']
```

If URL has product then store it main list.

Example URL:   https://www.americanflags.com/flags/police-fire-thin-line-ems.html
Example Page[image]:

**Problem**

Some URLs have more categories, so i want to scrape each category's URL and loop through it until found the product Product page and store it in main list.

Example URL:  https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags.html

[image]

Here is my Code so far:

```
mainlist = list()
for indx, producturl in enumerate(listofurls):
    res = requests.get(producturl, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
    #if there are products it will generate an erro and url will save in main list
    try:
        #scrape categories urls
        innercategoriesurl = [cateurl['href'] for cateurl in soup.select('div.wrapper >a')]
        while True:
            for num, innerproducturl in enumerate(innercategoriesurl):
                innercategoriesurl.pop(num)
                whileres = requests.get(innerproducturl, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
                whilesoup = bs(whileres.content, 'lxml')
                try:

                    innercategoriesurl.extend(
                        [s['href'] for s in soup.select('div.wrapper >a')]
                        )
                except:mainlist.append(t)
            if len(innercategoriesurl) == 0:
                break
    except:

        listofurls.pop(indx)
        mainlist.append(producturl)
```

Comment: You can't just dump code on us.  If this code isn't doing what you want, you have to _show us_ what it is doing, and _explain_ how that is different from what you wanted.

Comment: which part are you having trouble with?  If I were you I would use scrapy instead of BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 2):

You could get your goal with a function that invokes itself and checks for your condition.

Example uses `time` to gently request the different urls with some delay:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

url = 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags.html'

data = []

def check(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
    if soup.select_one('.product-item-link[href]'):
        return url

    time.sleep(2)

    for a in soup.select('a.slide'):
        if e:=check(a.get('href')):
            data.append(e)
            continue

check(url)
data
```

Output:

```
['https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/armed-forces-flags/armed-forces-bundles.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/armed-forces-flags/air-force-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/armed-forces-flags/army-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/armed-forces-flags/navy-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/armed-forces-flags/us-marine-corps-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/armed-forces-flags/coast-guard-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/armed-forces-flags/merchant-marine-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/armed-forces-flags/army-national-guard-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/veterans-commemorative-and-retirement-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/pow-mia-flags.html',
 'https://www.americanflags.com/flags/military-flags/service-banners.html',
...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I also wrote code but that was too lengthy and complicated as compared to your code.